# Online Interactive mathematics games for mathematicians or mathematicians-to-be!

Tags: reference-request, math-communication

I am aware that this is not a research level mathematics question. Also, it would not have a single answer (if any) and yet, I hoping that it will be considered as a community wiki question worthy of MO attention.

About four months ago, I have created a [website](http://maths4maryams.org/) in honor of Maryam Mirzakhani. Timothy Gowers has kindly introduced it as follows.

> [It is] a website in memory of Maryam Mirzahkani. I don’t mean that it
>   is a memorial website: rather, it has taken an important aspect of her
>   life — her interaction with other like-minded mathematicians at a
>   young age — and aims to facilitate such interactions for others, by
>   the setting up of maths4maryams groups.

It is just a start of an idea and with my nonexisting website making ability it is growing very slowly. I am hoping that the members of each group and the groups find their own way of mathematically interacting with each other without any intervention by the admins of the website (that is currently one!). However, I thought it would be nice if I could add one or two online interactive games on the main page of the website to break the ice.

Considering that the users of the website Mathematics 4 Maryams are mathematically inclined, I am wondering if there is any online interactive (mathematics) game you might want to suggest.

Comment: Does it have to be some _games_? You can also put some interesting problems there and get some ideas from [project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) which itself has a dedicated forum.

Comment: @polfosol No, for the question; thanks for the suggestion. You know, I just wanted to be less involved personally. But then, it seems I would miss many intresting things like Project Euler.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing that you have in mind, but there's a text-based interactive adventure game called *[A Beauty Cold and Austere](http://ifdb.tads.org/viewgame?id=y9y7jozi0l76bb82)*. It was written by Mike Spivey and is highly mathematical.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is some information about Mirzakhani, including a quote from her, in the game.

Answer (score 2):

I found this selection by Alexander Bogomolny quite attractive, it has a great variety that test different skills:

[Cut the knot: Interactive Mathematics Miscellany and Puzzles](https://www.cut-the-knot.org)

According to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-the-Knot) it received several rewards. It is described as *"a resource that would help learn, if not math itself, then, at least, ways to appreciate its beauty."*

Comment: Personally, I used Cut the Knot a lot and it really deserved whatever rewards it received.